java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tinder/scarlet/messageadapter/builtin/BuiltInMessageAdapterFactory
I'm developing an application using websocket api and in order to implement it properly, I'm using Scarlet library because it's so similar to Retrofit but I keep getting this error. I use the 0.2.5-SNAPSHOT version of this library and trying to use coroutines.
Here is my code for Scarlet configuration:
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
val interceptor = loggingInterceptor.apply {
    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
}

val httpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .readTimeout(2000 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .followRedirects(false)
    .connectTimeout(3000 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
    .build()

val scarlet = Scarlet(
    OkHttpWebSocket (
        httpClient,
        OkHttpWebSocket.SimpleRequestFactory(
            { Request.Builder().url(baseUrl).build()},
            { ShutdownReason.GRACEFUL }
        )
    ),
    Scarlet.Configuration (
        backoffStrategy = LinearBackoffStrategy(3000),
        messageAdapterFactories = listOf(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory()),
        streamAdapterFactories = listOf(CoroutinesStreamAdapterFactory()),
    )
)

val bitService = scarlet.create(BitService::class.java)
bitService.authenticateUser(
    RequestDataFrame(
        messageType = 0,
        sequenceNumber = 0,
        functionName = "AuthenticateUser",
        payloadRequest = "{UserName:, Password:}"
    )
)

I added the required maven repository for getting the snapshot version.
Also if you know any better solution for websocket implementation which is similar to Retrofit in a clean way , please let me know !
